# Powershell get childitem filename masks

Tags: powershell, filenames, masking, get-childitem

I'm working on a script that goes through folders with multiple .pdf-files in it. Only when the name of the file fits one of two masks, Powershell should continue executing certain steps. Else it should continue to search for the next file fitting the mask.

I've used:

```
Get-ChildItem $PATH -Filter "*TEXT-TXT-*" -Recurse -Force |Foreach-Object {

        write-host $_.Name
```

But this filters only hardcoded. How to use a mask and preferable use two mask as filter? The masks should be:

- "##-##-#### XXXX-XXX-XXXX-XX.PDF"
- "##-##-#### XXXX-XXX-XXX-XXXX-XX.PDF"

Where # are any numbers and X are any non-number characters.

Hope this is possible.

Comment: you will need to use the full regex engine to do that sort of thing. so, start by filtering for  `*.pdf`, then use either `.Where()` or pipe to `Where-Object` and put in the two regex patterns that you need to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for this you can use regular expressions, add several conditions to them through "or" for example as follows

```
Get-ChildItem $PATH -Filter "*TEXT-TXT-*" -Recurse -Force|Where-Object {($_.name -match '\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4} \w{4}-\w{3}-\w{3}-\w{4}-\w{2}.PDF') -or($_.name -match '\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4} \w{4}-\w{3}-\w{4}-\w{2}.PDF')}
```

in this expression it is enough to substitute the name of the file transmitted by the piping